# Ember hasMany self referential association not returning values

Tags: ember.js

I set up a `hasMany` association on a model pointing back to itself. Since we are using Cassandra with a compound primary key on the back end there is no specific `id` column. When I do `model.versions` it returns an empty array. I expected it to return 13 (that is how many different versions with the same ID there are).

Model:

```
App.Automobile = DS.Model.extend
  automobileId: DS.attr('string')
  version: DS.attr('string')
  identifier: DS.attr('string')
  name: DS.attr('string')
  description: DS.attr('string')
  versionName: DS.attr('string')
  automobileVersions: DS.hasMany('automobile', async: true)
```

Calling it:

```
auto = @.get('model')
console.log "sR: " + auto.get('automobileVersions')
auto.get('automobileVersions').then ((autoVer) =>
  console.log "autoVer: " + autoVer.get('length')
)
```

The `console.log "autoVer: " + autoVer.get('length')` comes back as `autoVer: 0`. It should be thirteen.

Comment: Can you show the json returned from both requests?

Comment: @Kingpin2k With much shame I have to ask how I can get the JSON to post

Comment: ah, no shame, if you open up the dev tools in chrome, it has a network tab, and in the network tab it'll show all of your requests (you may have to refresh).  and if you click on a particular requests, it'll have a few tabs, one of them being the response, with the json.  (I'd imagine modern IE, FF, Safari all have something similar in their dev tools)